# Split UIViewController implementation into multiple source files

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, extending-classes

I'm new to iOS development and I'm looking for a good example. Can someone give me a link?

#### My problem:

I made a project with some `UIViewController`s, but I have a controller that has a lot of methods. How can I split my `UIViewController` into multiple classes?

Finally, I want just split my `UIViewController` into multiple files but I want my `UIViewController` working as if all the methods were in the same file.

If someone can give me a good book or explain me how it works that would be great.

Comment: Please do not ask for links as StackOverflow is not a link site. Imagine how worthless any answer containing only a link would become once the link becomes invalid - yes, the interweb does not last forever.... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [categories](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html). You create a separate header and implementation file for each category, where the header looks something like:

```
@interface MyClass (SomethingMethods)

... // Function declarations

@end
```

Then, you implement it like this:

```
@implementation MyClass (SomethingMethods)

... // Implementation

@end
```

This allows you to split the class into separate source files by what the methods do or whatever you want. However, remember **every category must have a unique name**. The name is not really used anywhere in any important way, but it must be unique, otherwise you will get compile errors.

Note that categories **do not allow you to declare properties or instance variables**. You can only declare and implement methods. This means that you will have to declare all your instance variables and `@property`s in your main source file and implementation. See the [official Apple documentation on categories](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can read about Categories on the Apple documentation. You can do something similar to what you are wanting:

[Customizing Existing Classes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html)

But, I really don't know why would you want to do that. You could organize your code using pragma marks.